# Wayland freezes while playing video on 18.04 using VLC

Tags: 18.04, vlc, wayland

I tried Wayland while logging in and it works fine until I try to play some local video file using VLC. Ubuntu freezes completely and I have to power off by pressing the power button. It works fine in the default Xorg Ubuntu session. Is it a bug ? If there is a fix, kindly let me know.

I use 18.04.2.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it a VLC bug than a Wayland bug. I tried playing the video using the default `Video` player and `Kodi`. Both worked fine.